# Accessing Form Objects - Access 2013 VBA - outside procedures

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to check if a checkbox is checked in order to make a decision.

I've tried all of these of cant get it.

```
Me.chkExpInvoice.Value
SwitchBoard.chkExpInvoice.Value
Form.SwitchBoard.chkExpInvoice.Value
Forms.SwitchBoard.chkExpInvoice.Value
AllForms.SwitchBoard.chkExpInvoice.Value
AllForms(0).chkExpInvoice.Value
```

Comment: Is there an error message when you try `Forms!SwitchBoard!chkExpInvoice.Value`?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks, for the input. I finally realized that out of all my check boxes, the one I started experimenting with was misspelled, missing the h in chk. My head hurts, its been over an hour, but now I can move on without redesigning everything :)

Comment: You can also use http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm for reference in the future.  It's a great resource for how to reference objects on Access.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to bookmark that since I'll be working in Access a lot for the time period.